# validate same number exists more than 6 times in UITextFied in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, validation, numbers

i just want to know how to validate number in Textfield. i have an UiTextField in that i have to enter 16 digit number, while typing i can repeat same number for maximum 6 times when user try to enter more than 6 times the same number means i need to show warning

for Example 1231125641678923 is accepted
            2277890652222256 its not accepted see the number 2 is repeated more than 6 times

here my sample code but its not working for me

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

//        var ErrorAlert:UIAlertView!

    if textField == sampleTextField{

        var updatedTextString : NSString = textField.text! as NSString
        updatedTextString = updatedTextString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

        if textField.text!.containsString(string) {


//                ErrorAlert=UIAlertView.init(title: "Error!", message: "please Enter Valid Policy Number", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
//                ErrorAlert.show()

            NSLog("error")

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var number = "1123455324222323"

for digit in 0...9
{
  if number.componentsSeparatedByString("\(digit)").count > 7
  { print("found more than 6 times : \(digit)") }
}
```

Comment: hi thanx for your answer its working good but iam getting alert often when i enter another number also

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {        

        var updatedTextString : NSString = textField.text! as NSString
        updatedTextString = updatedTextString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

        if (textField.text!.rangeOfString(string, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil) {

            var length:NSInteger = string.characters.count

            let str:Character = string[advance(string.startIndex, count(string)-1)]

            var integerCount:NSInteger = 0

            for digit in 0...count(string)-1
            {

                let str1:Character = string[advance(string.startIndex, digit)]

                if (str == str1)
                {
                    integerCount++
                }
            }

            if(integerCount > 6)
            {
                return false
            }
            else
            {
                return true
            }

        }
    return true
    }
```

Comment: hi balaji what is count denotes var length:NSInteger = count(string) i getting error

Answer (score 0):

var textValue = "112333454333243132" for number in (0..textValue.text.count ?? 0)-1 { if number.componentsSeparatedByString("(number)").count > 5 { print("textValue is more than 4 times : (number)") } }

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).